# How to access the first element of a List?

Tags: c#, list

In the `CourseFirst` method the program checks if the `courselist` is empty and if the user enters the right number of course.Finally returns the number of course `y`.

```
public static int CourseFirst(int y)
{
    if (courselist.Count() == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please add course first");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give course");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y)
            || y >= courselist.Count() + 1 || y <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give course that allready created (1,2,3,...etc)");
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

After the `ShowDataMenu` method asks from user choices to show the data.

```
public static void ShowDataMenu()
{
    ...
    else if (x == 5)
    {
        int t = 0;
        ...
        else
        {
            CourseData();
            t = CourseFirst(courselist.Count);
            Student.showStudentPerCourse(t - 1);
        }                       
    }

}
```

Finally the `showStudentPerCourse` method shows every student per course.

```
public static void showStudentPerCourse(int courseID)
{
    List<int> studentsIDs = Helper.courselist[courseID].studentIDlist;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentsIDs.Count(); i++)
    {
        int stID = studentsIDs[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Student's name is: {0}" , Helper.studentlist[stID].Fullname)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the for loop doesnt work if the user enters 1 for the first course(first element of `courselist`) , but works fine if 2 or more cources were create(input from user 2,3,4..).

In `AddCourse` is how the `courselist` is filled.

```
public static void AddCourse()
         {             
              Console.WriteLine("Course name");             
              string cname = Console.ReadLine();  
              Course cou = new Course(Helper.courselist.Count() + 1, cname);             
              Helper.courselist.Add(cou);         
         }
```

Comment: Could you show how do you fill the _courseList_ list?

Comment: side note: `t`, `x` `y` are bad names for variables, use these only for variables with very small scope. In particular, don't use it as a function parameter `int CourseFirst(int y)`: give it a name so when you need to call `CourseFirst` you understand what is the meaning of the parameter without need to read the function body

Comment: `public static void AddCourse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Course name");
            string cname = Console.ReadLine();
            Course cou = new Course(Helper.courselist.Count() + 1, cname);
            Helper.courselist.Add(cou);
        }`

Comment: In `showStudentPerCourse` you use `Helper.courselist`, but in the rest of the code it's just `courselist`, are those the same?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: I suspect you actually just want `courseList[courseID - 1]`. That way a `courseID` of 1 refers to the first course (`courseList[0]`), and a `courseID` of 2 refers to the source course (`courseList[1]`)` etc. It's hard to say for sure without a [mcve] though - the question's not very clear.

Comment: (It also doesn't help to add methods in comments - put it in the *question*.)

Comment: If i write `courseList[courseID - 1]` the program crush when the user enters 1.

Comment: The problem is that `studentsIDs.Count` is 0 when the user enter 1 for the first course and is 1 for the rest of the courses 2,3,4...

Answer (score 0):

Almost all collections/arrays/list are always zero (0) based index in C#. It means the first element will always be on the 0 index.

Let say `courselist` has 1 element.

Input: 1 (courseID) => `Helper.courselist[courseID]` will return `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Input: 0 (courseID) => `Helper.courselist[courseID]` will return first element.

Comment: Yes , this is correct. But when the user enters 0 , then the: `while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y)
            || y >= courselist.Count() + 1 || y <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give course that allready created (1,2,3,...etc)");
        }` works and asks from the user to give the right number(1). Also if the `courselist` has 2 elements. The Input: 2 works fine.